# How to disable Google Chrome download bar?

Tags: google-chrome

How to disable Google Chrome download bar from popping up every time I download something? I prefer to  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> to see my downloads status when I actually want it, not to see a log of every thing I save all the time.

Comment: Was an option in chrome://flags/ until ver 22.  Since then, it seems the only option has been an extension that jacks with download history.

Comment: I believe that CoolNovo has a simplified download manager that tucks away all downloads into a button at the top instead of a bar at the bottom. (http://coolnovo.com/, no affiliation whatsoever)

Answer (score 7):

You can use this extension that disables the downloads bar but does nothing else: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-download-bar/gjdldigdojpjlmphnogmcmhojfadfmem

Comment: [NoDownloadShelf](https://github.com/aoirint/NoDownloadShelf) works with latest chrome

Answer (score 4):

In my current Chromium (47.0.2509.0), in chrome://flags, you can set "Download Status in Notification Center" to "Enabled" which will display downloads in a Notification popup instead of the downloads bar.

Comment: Seemingly no longer available in version 78 at least.

Comment: Why is it that all the useful `chrome://flags` settings are removed after a short time?  Every single time I find solution to an annoyance using `chrome://flags`, the setting is no longer there.  Pretty lame.

Comment: Present in Chrome 101 as "Enable download bubble".