# How to hide Chrome download bar

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

My project is to not allow the download bar to auto popup, so I tried to Google search. Many results are shown using Chrome Extensions, but I don't want to use Chrome Extensions to solve the problem. Users are using Chrome **versions 77-84** at the moment.

According to the
[How to disable Google Chrome download bar?](https://superuser.com/questions/706084/how-to-disable-google-chrome-download-bar), some people suggested **chrome://flags**, but this method cannot be used now.

So, are there any ideas on how to disable the Chrome **download bar** (e.g. Group Policy, registry)? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, the following link might be helpful to you: https://windowsloop.com/auto-hide-download-bar-chrome/

Answer (score 6):

Chrome doesn't feature any built-in means to turn the download shelf off,
so extensions are required.

The following extensions will do the task. Try them out to decide on the one
you like best:

- [Always Clear Downloads in Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/always-clear-downloads-in/efoelbbfbknfhpmgclpcdbkoieedkkai)
- [Disable Download Bar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-download-bar/gjdldigdojpjlmphnogmcmhojfadfmem?hl=en-GB)
- [Disable Download Bar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-download-bar/nhdeokdadlelojjohmmpjjdjbhgimohi?hl=en) (another one)
- [AutoHideDownloadsBar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autohidedownloadsbar/gkmndgjgpolmikgnipipfekglbbgjcel)
- [Close download bar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/close-download-bar/bkfclmjddajodogcbpohgfpdkgdecgmg)

If you want to use any of the extensions in Incognito mode, right-click
the extension icon, select Manage extensions and enable "Allow In Incognito".

To still access the Chrome downloads manager, open the Chrome menu and click
"Downloads", or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc! For future internet travelers- I evaluated all of them and "AutoHideDownload" bar is the best choice if you want to auto hide after the download completes. They also have settings to completely disable the downloads bar if that's what you're into. Developer has updated the extension as of March 2022.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autohidedownloadsbar/gkmndgjgpolmikgnipipfekglbbgjcel/related

Comment: I like that first one, "Always Clear Downloads in Chrome", because it let me choose how many seconds to keep the download bar at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 5):

There is a flag currently in version 103.0.5060.134 called "Enable download bubble" (#download-bubble) that prevents the download bar from appearing at the bottom of the screen and replaces it with behavior similar to Firefox.

chrome://flags/#download-bubble

This may not be helpful to the original question author because I don't know when this flag first appeared. It's not the same as automatically hiding the downloads bar, but for me it was sufficient to solve my problem so I figured I'd post for general/future reference.

Answer (score 2):

#### Enable "Download Bubbles" [Experimental feature]

Open url `chrome://flags/#download-bubble` and toggle feature

Comment: You could enhance your answer by describing what this does.

Comment: And as of a recent Chrome release the download bar doesn't even exist, and the bubble is the only option.