# How can I make Chrome's download bar smaller?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome has a really big download bar which seems to take up a significant amount of screen real estate, as can be seen in the image below.

[image]

Is there a way to make this bar smaller (like half its size) or just to get rid of it after a short delay?

Comment: There's another post asking this same question with answers already here - https://superuser.com/questions/1595786/how-to-hide-chrome-download-bar

Comment: I just use the tiny little notification in the lower left corner.